# How can I auto deploy Fabric Crashlytics Beta with Circle CI in Android

Tags: android, circleci, google-fabric, fabric-beta

I want to auto deploy to Beta Fabric With Circle CI in Android

I add command in `config.yml` but it not work

```
deployDevelop:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/code
      - run:
          name: Deploy develop to fabric beta
          command:  |
            ./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
```

Error at console CI :

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./gradlew :app:assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Exited with code 128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase. Circle CI does not support building when PR is opened as [mentioned](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/build-only-pull-request-to-a-specific-branch/903) here. But building application take almost 10 minutes. If you open a pull request immediately after push commits to git, Circle CI detects the PR and it’ll give the url with ${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST} environment.

You might find this [medium](https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/android-automated-build-with-circle-ci-ded9c0a4d931) post help full.